# jQuery Error - xyz is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui

I am suddenly getting a most unwelcome error on this [page](http://site427.mysite4now.net/tazthedog/site1/printing-whiteplastisolinks.html):

> Error: $("#accordion").accordion is not a function

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            // Accordion
            $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h4", autoHeight: false, collapsible: true });

            //hover states on the static widgets
            $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
            );

            // controls the sidebar navigation action               
            $('.interior #subContent > ul > li > a.drop').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle("slow");
                 return false;
            });

            $(window).ready(function() {
                $('li.products ul').show();
                $('li.technical ul').show();
                $('li.tips ul').show();
            }); 

        });
    </script>
```

I has worked for weeks and today...errors all the way.

I would appreciate any help in determining the cause of the error.

Thanks.

Comment: did you accidently remove the jquery or  jquery UI script?

Comment: @fmz - I recommend looking at your site with Firefox's Firebug plugin (http://getfirebug.com/), you can use the "Net" tab and it will show that you're getting six 404 errors so you know exactly which JavaScript files are not being loaded.

Comment: John,  I use firebug but have ignored the Net functionality. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.accordion.js"></script>
```

does not link to anything anymore.

> The requested URL
>   /svn/tags/latest/ui/ui.accordion.js
>   was not found on this server.

Comment: Right you are. It appears that there are problems with the jquery ui server. I found this link on Google and have replace the above link with it: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js

Thanks.